# group mysql subcategories and categories

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I went through all the questions on SOF and did my homework but still couldn't find or understand what I am looking for now I have 2 tables 'category' and 'subcategory' they are like:

category:

```
id (int)
title (varchar)
description (varchar)
```

subcategory

```
id (int)
cid (int) // This is same as category id.
title (varchar)
description (varchar)
```

now I want to join and group both of them how do I do it like this

```
#category1
-subcat1.1
-subcat1.2

#category2
-subcat2.1
-subcat2.2
```

and so on..

and I also have seen people call there values like `$row['cat.title']` for category title and `$row['subcat.title']` as subcategory title and so on.. I think they use 'as' or something like that can anyone help please? I am using php to do the queries.

Comment: are you using PHP to do query your DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   SELECT sc.title AS subcat_title, c.title AS cat_title
     FROM subcategory AS sc
LEFT JOIN category AS c
       ON c.id = sc.cid
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't display the data instead it shows undefined variable both the tables are having same column name as title just the id and cid are different. and it shows undefined variable when i called it like $row['c.title'] and $row['sc.title']

Comment: In my example, there are no `subcat.title` - just `subcat_title`. Just rename it.

Comment: I am using this: SELECT sc.title AS title, c.title AS title
     FROM subcategory AS sc
LEFT JOIN category AS c
       ON c.id = sc.cid

Comment: You can't do `AS title` twice because second one will overwrite first. And use in PHP key that you set in query after `AS` -> `$row['title']`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select subcat.subcat_title, cat.cat_title from subcategory subcat left join category cat on subcat.cid = cat.id
```

For for information on storing the hierarchical data checkout the following link

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/